# How to write my conditional logic inside my custom React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a custom React hook. The *scrolling* target element can either be the `myref.current` or the `window` object.

If it's the `myref.current` target value I want to use the `scrollTop` method, if it's the `window` object I want to use `pageYOffset` method (since `scrollTop` method isn't available for the `window`).

How do I create this function and write this in a clean way?

```
const useMyHook = (target: 'ref' | 'window') => {
  const [fade, setFade] = useState(false);
  const myRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   const onScroll = () => {
  //     if (window.pageYOffset > 50) {
  //       setFade(true);
  //     } else {
  //       setFade(false);
  //     }
  //   };

  //   window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  //   return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  // }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const node = target === 'ref' ? scrollRef.current : window;

    const onScroll = () => {
      if (node) {
        if (node.scrollTop > 50) {
          setFade(true);
        } else {
          setFade(false);
        }
      }
    };
    if (node) {
      node.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    }
    return () => node?.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  }, []);
  return { myRef, fade };
};

export default useMyHook;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have implemented this way:

```
// node - any element you want to add event listener to, For eg: scrollRef.current or the window object
const useMyHook = (node) => {
  const [fade, setFade] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    if (!node) return

    const onScroll = () => {
        const verticalScroll = node === window ? node.pageYOffset : node.scrollTop; 

        if (verticalScroll > 50) {
          setFade(true);
        } else {
          setFade(false);
        }
    };

    node.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    
    return () => node.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  }, [node]);

  return fade;
};

export default useMyHook;
```

PS: Not sure why you used `myRef`.

Comment: Thanks, in one component I have to use the `window` object as the scrolling target and in another one the ref (React `useRef`), regarding some issues I had within a material ui dialog. In your example it's only based on a ref because `window` doesn't has access to the `scrollTop` method

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest in my opinion (also removed myRef as its not in used):

```
   const useMyHook = node => {
      const [fade, setFade] = useState(false);
    
      useEffect(() => {
    
        if (node){
        const verticalScroll = node === window ? node.pageYOffset : node.scrollTop; 

        const onScroll = () => setFade(verticalScroll > 50);
    
        node.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
        }
    
        return () => node?.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
      }, [node]);
    
      return fade;
    };
    
    export default useMyHook;
```

Comment: Thanks, in one component I have to use the `window` object as the scrolling target and in another one the ref (React `useRef`), regarding some issues I had within a material ui dialog. In your example it's only based on a ref because `window` doesn't has access to the `scrollTop` method

Comment: @meez added the distinction if its window or ref